# Boost Graph Library, fix node size

Tags: c++, vertex, boost-graph

I am constructing graph with Boost Graph Library and Graphviz.
In my code, I have a class that export a Graph to a .dot format.
I setup the properties of the graph with the following lines:

```
dynamic_properties dp;

dp.property("rankdir", boost::make_constant_property<Graph*>(std::string("TB")));
dp.property("node_id", get(&VertexP::tag, m_graph));
dp.property("label", get(&VertexP::tag, m_graph));
dp.property("shape", get(&VertexP::shape, m_graph));
dp.property("style", get(&VertexP::style, m_graph));
dp.property("pos", get(&VertexP::pos, m_graph));
dp.property("label", get(&ArrowP::symbol, m_graph));
dp.property("color", get(&ArrowP::color, m_graph));
dp.property("style", get(&ArrowP::style, m_graph));
write_graphviz_dp(ss, m_graph, dp);
```

I am trying to use the `fixedsize` keyword of graphviz and the `width` and `height` keywords to fix the size of my node (they have different sizes depending on the quantity of text in the label).

I would like to setup it from the `dp.property` method. The objective being to add the following line in my .dot document:

```
node [ fixedsize = true, width = 1.1, height = 1.1]
```

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
dp.property("fixedsize", boost::make_constant_property<VertexP*>(std::string("true")));
dp.property("width", boost::make_constant_property<VertexP*>(std::string("1")));
dp.property("height", boost::make_constant_property<VertexP*>(std::string("1")));
```

**Do you know how I can set the attribute fixedsize to my vertex in my dot file from dp.property.**

Comment: I've first completed your sample to be self-contained. This saves others at least 10 minutes (likely a lot more, since there are not very many Boost Graph experienced contributors). http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3adbd0bfb2320aca In the future, please include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a.k.a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [property maps](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/property_map/doc/ReadablePropertyMap.html), the key_type (`boost::property_traits<PMap>::key_type`) informs the library what type of object the property belongs to:

- `graph_traits<G>::vertex_descriptor` attaches the attribute to objects of node type (vertices)
- `graph_traits<G>::edge_descriptor` attaches attributes to the edges
- `G*` attaches attributes at the graph level

Therefore you need to use `vertex_descriptor` instead of `VertexP*` for these maps:

```
dp.property("fixedsize", boost::make_constant_property<Graph::vertex_descriptor>(+"true"));
dp.property("width",     boost::make_constant_property<Graph::vertex_descriptor>(1));
dp.property("height",    boost::make_constant_property<Graph::vertex_descriptor>(1));
```

Note that default streaming operations are used so there is no need to specifically convert to `std::string`

> Note though that the attributes are being written to temporary streams, so `std::boolalpha` is not honored. Also note that using a string literal would lead to the propertymap instantiating with `char const(&)[5]`, which is why `+"true"` is used (decaying to `char const*`).

### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6513a07e5b92d5f2)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

struct VertexP {
    std::string tag, shape, style, pos;
};

struct ArrowP {
    std::string symbol, color, style;
};

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
    VertexP, ArrowP>;

int main() {
    Graph g;

    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("rankdir", boost::make_constant_property<Graph*>(+"TB"));
    dp.property("node_id", get(&VertexP::tag,   g));
    dp.property("label",   get(&VertexP::tag,   g));
    dp.property("shape",   get(&VertexP::shape, g));
    dp.property("style",   get(&VertexP::style, g));
    dp.property("pos",     get(&VertexP::pos,   g));
    dp.property("label",   get(&ArrowP::symbol, g));
    dp.property("color",   get(&ArrowP::color,  g));
    dp.property("style",   get(&ArrowP::style,  g));

    dp.property("fixedsize", boost::make_constant_property<Graph::vertex_descriptor>(+"true"));
    dp.property("width",     boost::make_constant_property<Graph::vertex_descriptor>(1));
    dp.property("height",    boost::make_constant_property<Graph::vertex_descriptor>(1));

    add_edge(
            add_vertex({"foo", "diamond", "dotted", "0,1"}, g),
            add_vertex({"bar", "circle", "dashed", "1,1"}, g),
            {"foo-bar", "blue", "dashed"},
            g);

    write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, g, dp);
}
```

Prints

```
digraph G {
rankdir=TB;
bar [fixedsize=true, height=1, label=bar, pos="1,1", shape=circle, style=dashed, width=1];
foo [fixedsize=true, height=1, label=foo, pos="0,1", shape=diamond, style=dotted, width=1];
foo->bar  [color=blue, label="foo-bar", style=dashed];
}
```